# How can I play quick sounds in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, playsound

I am trying to make a metronome in Delphi. To this end, I use a TTimer to play the beeps at the needed BPM :

```
procedure TTestForm.TimerMetronomeTimer(Sender: TObject);
    PlaySound(PWideChar('100ms_sound.wav'), 0, SND_ASYNC);
end;
```

this works fine until you get under 1000ms intervals on the timer. Then it starts breaking down by cutting the sound, playing it delayed, etc...
How can I make this work ?

Comment: Timer is never guaranteed to fire at the specified interval. The smaller the interval, the more visible will be interference from regular Windows message processing.

Comment: Use a multimedia timer instead. And definitely don't use PlaySound() with a file when high performance is needed

Comment: @RemyLebeau Which API *should* be used when high-performance is needed?

Comment: @IanBoyd At the very least, consider loading the file into memory ahead of time and preloading its audio info into the output system using `waveOutPrepareHeader()` and then play its audio samples with `waveOutWrite()` when needed. But also consider more modern media APIs like DirectSound, XAudio2, etc that handle this for you.

Comment: This is what I did. Plays nicely up to 500BPM with waveOutWrite(), but the upper limit might be down to hardware variations across devices.